# bulk of file copy from local to DBFS server using multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to upload a bulk of files (say 100 gbs ) from some shared network path to database DBFS server.
I am using the below code and it is working fine. But i need to speed up the process by using multi threading concepts either using JSch and ExecutorService class thread pool

see my below code

```
public static void sftpConnection()throws JSchException, SftpException, IOException {


    System.out.println("Inside sftpConnection method");
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = null;
    Channel channel = null;
    String user = "oracle";
    //  String host ="";
    String host ="";

    Integer port =;
    String password ="";
    String Folder ="";
    String outputDir ="";
    String filema =".txt";
    ChannelSftp sftpChannel = null;
    try 
    {
        session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        System.out.println("Afer getting Session"+session);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setPassword(password);
        System.out.println("Set Password");
        session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications","publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");

        session.connect();
        System.out.println("Connection Successfull");
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        System.out.println("Channel Connection Succesfull");
        sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp)channel;

        File[] files = findFile(Folder, filema);
        for(File file : files) 
        {
            putFile(file, sftpChannel, outputDir);            

        }              
        File dir = new File(""); 
        dir.mkdirs(); 
    } 
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally 
    {
        if (sftpChannel != null) {
            sftpChannel.exit();
        }
        session.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Can any one help me how to implement JSch and ExecutorService to handle 100gbs of data from server to DBFS server. 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-threading could help with speeding up computation intensive processes by using multiple threads to parallelize the computation. But a simple file copying is NOT computation intensive, it's I/O intensive.

Running on multiple threads won't help you here. Your network bandwidth is the same, regardless of the number of pipes you're trying to funnel into it.

Comment: Hi Janos,It is not single simple file. We have a bulk of files with various extensions (.doc, .txt) and each file carry some gb size. more than 5000 files needs to be injected to oracle DBFS server and the restriction is i cant use more than java 6 :(

Comment: Regardless of the number of files, your bottleneck is the network bandwidth, not the CPU. Whether you have 1 of 10GB file or 10 of 1GB files, same thing. If you have millions of tiny files, you might have additional local disk I/O bottleneck, but given that your files are large (in fact very large), that's not an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Easy with Java8:

```
Arrays.stream(files).parallel()
             .forEach((f) -> putFile(f, sftpChannel, outputDir));
```

Note that `sftpChannel` must be thread-safe for this to work correctly, which might not give you a speedup in performance. I would create a channel per `put` operation, or use a connection pool to manage this for you.

You can control the amount of parallelism used by changing the size of the common forkjoin pool like this (passed as a JVM argument):

```
-Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=120
```

This will create a threadpool with 120 threads.